# SVN branches: Delete branch locally, but do not show up as modified

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch

I accidently went and synced up my branches folder resulting in a download of all the branches on my local harddisk (very huge in size)

Now how can I delete the branches locally but not show up in the svn as modified/missing?

I use [tortisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)

**Edit:**
Doing a system delete on the individual branches will show up missing. I don’t want that

[alt text http://img49.imageshack.us/img49/58/svnbranches.png](http://img49.imageshack.us/img49/58/svnbranches.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option, which I use, is to use [sparse directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html). In TortoiseSVN use the "Update to Revision..." submenu instead of Update, and set the "Update Depth". Also see [this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html#tsvn-dug-checkout-depth)
in the TortoiseSVN documentation, when it talks about Checkout depths, which applies to updates (when using "Update to Revision")

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .svn folder into the folder you want to delete. Then simply remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete (not svn delete but system delete) the branches on your local machine and the subversion server will not know a thing.

To clarify, this would be deleting the highest level folder.  You could then redownload specifically what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete any files and folder on a subversion working copy using the explorer (not using TortoiseSvn Delete!). They will appear again if you do an svn update. To prevent this, do the update on the branch you need only or remove the .svn folder in the upper directory.